# Apache2 rendering PHP only partially

Tags: apache-2.4, lamp, php7

I set up a lamp server on Ubuntu 16.04 and now I'm having this strange issue where PHP renders only partially. I also checked and the page works normally if use nginx or lighttpd.
Also, I created a phpinfo.php file and Apache is identifying PHP modules as usual, PHP file extension is included in the dir.conf file and there are no abnormal events logged by Apache under /varies/log

Any clues?

PS2: I'm not a webmaster, despite my familiarity with the terms, so I acknowledge I may sound like a layman.

What I'm setting up is a PHP (open source) application for my personal use, and I've done so multiple times using lamp before, for the same application, and never had a problem, except now that I moved to Ubuntu.

PS: a power surge killed my keyboard's Prtscr and other keys, so I had to shoot a photo of my phone's screen. It's alike for every page except for the index page, it is only partially rendered.

[Broken page](https://i.ibb.co/q150pds/IMG-20190416-155542288-HDR.jpg)

EDIT: Just managed to run the same page on NGINX, no problem so far.
[image]

Comment: This is definitely a problem with your page. Are you missing the php opening tag `<?php` ?

Comment: @wurtel I'm going to check it, I never really checked, since it's an open source product and I never had issues with it.

Comment: @wurtel just checked it, the opening tag is okay. I also took a screenshot of the page running on nginx.